# Hyperledger Fabric: Enrollment check failed: Idemix enrollment information does not exist

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

we get this error whenever we try to run `fabric-ca-client`. Example below:

```
# fabric-ca-client register --url https://ica-org:7054 --id.name user-org --id.affiliation=org
2019/03/19 20:18:07 [INFO] Configuration file location: /home/fabric-ca-client-config.yaml
2019/03/19 20:18:07 [INFO] TLS Enabled
2019/03/19 20:18:07 [ERROR] Enrollment check failed: Idemix enrollment information does not exist
Error: Enrollment information does not exist. Please execute enroll command first. Example: fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://user:userpw@serverAddr:serverPort
```

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when `fabric-ca-client` cannot find any X509 or Idemix identity. `fabric-ca-client` needs to be initialized with an identity (except when its being used to `enroll` a user). It first tries to load an X509 identity from the `mspdir` location specified in the `fabric-ca-client-config.yaml` file or the `-M` command line argument which takes precedence over `mspdir` in config file. And if its not able to find X509 identity it will look for an idemix identity. If this fails as well it displays the error in question.

For X509 identity:

- its public cert needs to be in `signcerts`
- and private key needs to be in `keystore`
- and the public cert of the authority who issued the public/private keypair needs to be in `cacerts` folder (if an intermediate ca was used then its cert needs to be in `intermediatecerts`)

all the folders above are under the `mspdir`

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1
A potential cause if the folder indicated by FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME is not created you'll get that error. You have to check if FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME points to an existing folder. This happens too when indicating a wrong MSP path
exp

```
fabric-ca-client gencrl -M ~/wrong_path
```

Solution2:

Resolution to issue fabric-ca-client identity list command is as follows:

1. start the network with the CA option

   ```
   ./network.sh up -ca
   ```
2. after the network is up, navigate to (assumes you are already in the test-network directory):

   ```
   cd organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com
   ```
3. export cert path using this command:

   ```
   export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES=$PWD/ca/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
   ```
4. export fabric-ca-client home using this command:

   ```
   export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=$PWD
   ```
5. issue the following command:

   ```
   fabric-ca-client identity list
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use TLS, you should be using the `--tls.certfiles` flag or set the `FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_TLS_CERTFILES` environment variable when using the `fabric-ca-client` command. This should hold the full path to your organisation's TLS certificate.