# Hyperledger Fabric: Why doesn't cryptogen generate all the necessary crypto material to register new users?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am using cryptogen to generate all of the crypto material for the Fabric network I am building. I can successfully bring the network up and deploy chaincode. However, I am running into problems when trying to register a new user. I am following along with the asset-transfer-private-data tutorial, and after deploying the chaincode, I run

```
fabric-ca-client register --caname ca.org1 --id.name org1-client --id.secret org1-password --id.type client --mspdir ./config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1/msp
```

and get the error

```
2020/10/03 12:20:11 [INFO] Configuration file location: /home/user/network3.2/config/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1/fabric-ca-client-config.yaml
2020/10/03 12:20:11 [ERROR] Enrollment check failed: Idemix enrollment information does not exist
Error: Enrollment information does not exist. Please execute enroll command first. Example: fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://user:userpw@serverAddr:serverPort
```

There is no fabric-ca-client-config.yaml file. The mspdir I specify has the directories signcerts, keystore, and cacerts which according to [Hyperledger Fabric: Enrollment check failed: Idemix enrollment information does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55249365/hyperledger-fabric-enrollment-check-failed-idemix-enrollment-information-does) are needed. However, both the signcerts and keystore directories are empty whereas they should include a public cert and a private key respectively.

How can I generate these files? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cryptogen` is a utility to quickly allow you to generate crypto material to get things started.  It does not have any direct ties to Fabric CA (intentionally).

The only thing you can do is to leverage the CA key pair generated for each organization (under the `ca` folder) as the root key pair used when starting up an instance of Fabric CA.

Answer (score 0):

For Idemix, you can use [idemixgen](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/idemixgen.html?highlight=idemixgen#identity-mixer-msp-configuration-generator-idemixgen) tool.

But both cryptogen tool and idemixgen tool are used for testing purpose. For production level use, you have to use [Hyperledger Fabric CA](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/).

cryptogen is an utility for generating Hyperledger Fabric key material. It is provided as a means of preconfiguring a network for testing purposes. It would normally not be used in the operation of a production network.

Link: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/commands/cryptogen.html?highlight=cryptogen#cryptogen